# Decoding Exchange Rate JSON in SwiftUI

Tags: json, fetch, swiftui

I am trying to decode https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest, provided by Exchange Rates API. I'm applying several tutorials I found online, but when I apply my own details, I get an error. My code looks as following:

```
struct Response: Codable {
    var results: [Result]
}

struct Result: Codable {
    let base: String
    let date: String
    let rates: [String:Double]
}
```

The function to retrieve the data:

```
func loadData() {
    guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest") else {
        print("Invalid URL")
        return
    }
    let request = URLRequest(url: url)
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        if let data = data {
            if let decodedResponse = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data) {
                // we have good data – go back to the main thread
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    // update our UI
                    self.results = decodedResponse.results
                }
                // everything is good, so we can exit
                return
            }
        }
        // if we're still here it means there was a problem
        print("Fetch failed: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown error")")
    }.resume()
}
```

And my view:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ExchangeRateTest: View {
    @State private var results = [Result]()

    var body: some View {
                List(results, id: \.base) { item in
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text(item.base)
            }
        }.onAppear(perform: loadData)
    }
}
```

The error I get is: Fetch Failed: Unknown Error, suggesting that the app is not able to read the online data. What can cause this?

It has nothing to do with my network connection; if I apply another JSON this approach works fine.

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: Please paste the URL into a browser and **read** the JSON. There is neither a key `results` nor any array. You have to decode `Result.self`. And **never `try?` in  a `Decoding` context**, `catch` the error. It's very descriptive.

Comment: Thanks Vadian, I understand. I see now that this is also the difference with the JSON where I did get it to work.... Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can read like this:

```
struct RateResult: Codable {
    let rates: [String: Double]
    let base, date: String
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var results = RateResult(rates: [:], base: "", date: "")

    func loadData() {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest") else {
            print("Invalid URL")
            return
        }
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            if let data = data {
                if let decodedResponse = try? JSONDecoder().decode(RateResult.self, from: data) {
                    // we have good data – go back to the main thread
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        // update our UI
                        self.results = decodedResponse
                    }
                    // everything is good, so we can exit
                    return
                }
            }
            // if we're still here it means there was a problem
            print("Fetch failed: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown error")")
        }.resume()
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, Chris! Could you also point me in the right direction when it comes to fetching data from the 'rates' array? Displaying Text("\(results.base)"), and Text("\(results.date)") works fine, but as the 'rates' array doesn't have a key I can use to filter, I don't understand how to find rates for string "USD" for example?

Comment: Figured it out myself :). Set the different currencies in a separate struct, and updated View accordingly! Thanks, Chris

Comment: you are welcome and congrats for solving it yourself