# Displaying Foreign Exchange Dictionary Key / Value Pairs

Tags: swiftui, ios14

This is a follow up to a question asked at [Decoding Exchange Rate JSON in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61443473/decoding-exchange-rate-json-in-swiftui). I need some help with displaying the rate entries. I understand that is a dictionary key / value, but I'm not sure how to pull each string / double pair out of the structure.

Here is a typical string format received from the API:

```
{ 
  "rates": { "CAD": 1.5497, "HKD": 9.2404, "ISK":159.0 },
  "base": "EUR", 
  "date": "2020-11-27" 
}
```

```
struct RateResult: Codable {
    let rates: [String: Double]
    let base, date: String
}
```

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var results = RateResult(rates: [:], base: "", date: "")
    
    var curr = "EUR"
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Base Currency = \(results.base)")
        Text("Date = \(results.date)")
    
        List(results, id: \.results.rates) { item in
                   VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text(results.rates[item.key])
                    Text(results.rates[item.value])
            }
        }
        .onAppear(perform: loadData)
    }
    func loadData() {
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to explain your data, first.  How do you know that you will have data such that you have exactly three keys in rates?

Comment: If you don't know how many keys in the dictionary, get an array of keys with `Dictionary<Key, Value>.Keys`

Comment: Data format: there is always 1 date and 1 base key / value pair; the rates category can very with the request up to about 200 keys / value pairs.  The rates can be in any order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get an array of key/value pairs from dictionary, you can use `.map`:

```
let dict = ["one": 1, "two": 2, "three": 3]
let pairs = dict.map { ($0, $1) } // ex: [("one": 1"), ("three": 3), ("two": 2)]
```

So, you can use the same in a `List`:

```
List(results.rates.map { ($0, $1) }, id: \.0) { currency, rate in
   VStack {
      Text(currency)
      Text("\(rate)")
   }
}
```